# Compound Foreign Key INSERT

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, foreign-keys

I have 3 tables: `company`, `case` and `report`.

**company:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `db`.`company` (
  `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`name`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

**case:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `db`.`case` (
  `id` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `image` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `title` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `description` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `address` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `date` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `company_name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`company_name`, `id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_case_company`
    FOREIGN KEY (`company_name`)
    REFERENCES `db`.`company` (`name`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

**report:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `db`.`report` (
  `type` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  `image` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `description` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `approval` BINARY NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `date` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `case_company_name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `case_id` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `case_company_name`, `case_id`),
  INDEX `fk_report_case1_idx` (`case_company_name` ASC, `case_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_report_case1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`case_company_name` , `case_id`)
    REFERENCES `db`.`case` (`company_name` , `id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

When I insert a row into the `case` table using `phpMyAdmin`:

[image]

So the foreign key is working as I imagined. But when I try to insert a row in the `report` table, which is using a compound foreign key consisting of 2 columns, it looks like this:

[image]

Why is this? To me, it looks like the connection isn't made between the two tables and that `case_company_name` and `case_id` are just regular columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably it only means that phpmyadmin does not work with composite references this way. 
You can easily check existing constraints using `SHOW CREATE TABLE report`